# Failed prop type: ForwardRef(Button): prop type `component` is invalid: warning with material ui in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple React code and just put a button from material ui. But I got next warning:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: ForwardRef(Button): prop type `component` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`.
    in ForwardRef(Button) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Button)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Button)) (at App.js:12)
```

How to fix it?

My full code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const App = props => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Hello World
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

UPD:
My package.json file. In first look, I don't use any other prop-types package

```
{
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.4.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.4.1",
    "connected-react-router": "^6.5.2",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
...
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
...
    ],
    "development": [
        ....
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Please show your `package.json`. I suspect you are including an old version of the `prop-types` package (either directly or via some other package that you are including). I think it is complaining that [PropTypes.elementType](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.4.2/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L264) is undefined.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Look please on my package.json file, can I fix this warning?

Comment: [`react-router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v5.0.1/packages/react-router/package.json#L48) is referencing 15.6.2 of `prop-types` which does not support PropTypes.elementType (15.7.0 introduced it), but it's using "^15.6.2" which should support using 15.7.2 required by several of the other packages. Are you using yarn or npm?

Comment: @RyanCogswell I use yarn

Comment: Search your `yarn.lock` file for "15.6.2" to see if you have that version of `prop-types` being included -- I suspect you currently have multiple versions included.

Comment: @RyanCogswell you are right. material-ui has 15.7.2 version, other packages have 15.6.2. Can I fix it?